# How does this PHP function should look in Ruby? HMAC MD5

Tags: php, ruby, hmac, payu

I'm working on a payment integration and I've got an example code in PHP and trying to make it work in Ruby. So far with little success. Could someone check my implementation and fix if I'm doing something wrong? Thanks.

PHP code:

```php
/*
* HMAC HASH creation
* RFC 2104
* 
http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2104.txt
* 
* @param string $key Secret key for encryption
* @param string $data String to encode
*/
function hmac($key, $data) {
 $b = 64; // byte length for md5

 if (strlen($key) > $b) {
   $key = pack("H*", md5($key));
 }

 $key = str_pad($key, $b, chr(0x00));
 $ipad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x36));
 $opad = str_pad('', $b, chr(0x5c));
 $k_ipad = $key ^ $ipad;
 $k_opad = $key ^ $opad;

 return md5($k_opad . pack("H*", md5($k_ipad . $data)));
}
```

And my Ruby code:

```ruby
    #Calculate HMAC MD5 PayU hash for order.
    def hmac_calculation(key, data)
      b = 64

      if key.length > b 
        key = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(key)
        key = key.pack("H*")
      end

      key = key.ljust(b, 0x00.chr)
      ipad = ''.ljust(b, 0x36.chr)
      opad = ''.ljust(b, 0x5c.chr)

      k_ipad = key ^ ipad
      k_opad = key ^ opad

      return Digest::MD5.hexdigest(k_opad + Digest::MD5.hexdigest(k_ipad + data).pack('H*'))    

    end
```

-- UPDATED --

**Source string:**

7P0499016123456192013-07-08 10:50:367sku000226Loremipsumdolorsitamet4112011102103HUF158CCVISAMC41010

**Secret key:**

|n4A8~!3T8^3[8%I?8@Q

**Expected result:**

5142968ed89754e8d3a9b9a2469d21f2

I also got this site as the reference point however the above example does not match it.
http://hash.online-convert.com/md5-generator

Comment: What do you get from a simple print-trace, where does it differ from the PHP-implementation?

Comment: what is wrong, what's not happening the way you expect?  Can you provide an example input and expected output from the PHP code?

Comment: An MD5 hash (like the one generated by the site you linked to) is not the same as an HMAC MD5 hash and you should not expect them to give the same result.

Comment: So what about this on the site: Shared secret key used for the HMAC variant ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to write your own implementation of HMAC and many, many reasons not to. Just use the secure and well-tested implementation supplied by the [OpenSSL module](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/HMAC.html):

```
require "openssl"

key = "key"
data = "Hello"

digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('md5')
hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, key, data)
```

That's literally all you need.

Comment: Not reinventing the wheel is key here, nice.

Comment: I've been trying this with various Digest and HMAC options. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After all I tried this again and it seems the original requirement from PayU was wrong. Simply no solution matched their expected result.

```
    require 'openssl'

    key = '|n4A8~!3T8^3[8%I?8@Q'

    string = '7P0499016123456192013-07-08 10:50:367sku000226Loremipsumdolorsitamet4112011102103HUF158CCVISAMC41010'

    digest = OpenSSL::Digest.new('md5')

    hmac = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, key, string)

    puts hmac # Result = 7e84e5a7ceff25a8400ecf9608aed731
```